# Email address deleted cannot change iCloud settings on iPhone 5s and 6

Tags: ios

Email address no longer exists, and Apple ID has its new primary email address.  How do I change the iPhones existing iCloud settings as it keeps asking for password for the old email, I am putting in a password on the phone for an email address I know does not exist anymore, and it just shakes because of incorrect info.  User email address was a .com.au and is now a .net.au  Apple ID online could be changed fine and now uses the .net.au as primary address the .com.au was removed from there.  But the iPhone has this old email address stuck in its iCloud account setting.  How do I remove this account?  Any help appreciated as it surely cannot be this inflexible.

Answer (score 1):

Your Apple ID is not your email address… it it your AppleID.

That never changes.

It doesn't even have to *be* an email address, strictly speaking.

If you change the primary email address associated with it, that doesn't change the AppleID you sign in with - so if it used to be fred@xyz.com with a password of 123 & you changed the primary email address to fred@abc.net…

...you still sign in as fred@xyz.com, password 123
yet if Apple ever need to write to you, they'll write to fred@abc.net